# Querying Interfaces to find device with libpcap

Tags: c++, pcap, libpcap

Ok, so I have systems that could be plugged up to any number of ethernet ports on the target computer. My goal was to loop through each device, collect around ~20 packets, or if it's getting no data then skip it, until I found the data I was looking for, and select that device as my "capture device". Seems simple enough. However, I quickly learned that libpcap will not simply timeout if no data is coming in. So, I tried setting my capture device to non-blocking mode with pcap_setnonblock. However, this causes my destination port that I read to become totally wacked out. Here's my code. Open to suggestions on what might be happening, or potentially even a better way to do this. Thanks

PS. Don't knock the Type1 Type2 variable names, they are for obfuscation.

```
pcap_if_t *alldevs;
pcap_if_t *d;
pcap_t *fp;
struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
const u_char *pkt_data;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
const int FIND_DEVICE_PACKET_LIMIT = 20;

#ifdef WIN32
    if (pcap_findalldevs_ex(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING, NULL, &alldevs, errbuf) == -1) 
#else
    if (pcap_findalldevs(&alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
#endif
{
    cerr << "Error in pcap_findalldevs_ex: " << errbuf << endl;
    return;
}

// For each device, capture until timeout
//   or until a matching packet is found.
for(d=alldevs; d; d=d->next)
{        
    if ((fp = pcap_open_live(d->name,
                1514 /*snaplen*/,
                1 /*flags, 1=promiscuous, 0=not promiscuous*/,
                20 /*read timeout*/,
                errbuf)
                ) == NULL) 
    {
        cerr << endl << "Unable to open the adapter." << endl;
        continue;
    }

    int res = 0;
    int packetCounter = 0;


    pcap_setnonblock(fp, true, errbuf);

    // Capture at most FIND_DEVICE_PACKET_LIMIT packets
    //    to determine whether scanner is sending packets
    //    or no scanner found.
    while ((res = pcap_next_ex(fp, &header, &pkt_data)) >=0) {
        struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(pkt_data +  sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr*)(pkt_data + (iph->ihl*4)  + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        u_int destPort = ntohs(udph->dest);

        if (destPort==TYPE1_DATA_PORT || destPort==TYPE1_GPS_PORT) {
            detectedScanners->type1 = true;
        } else if (destPort==TYPE2_DATA_PORT || destPort==TYPE2_STATUS_PORT || destPort==TYPE2_NMEA_PORT) {
            detectedScanners->type2 = true;
        }

        if (++packetCounter > FIND_DEVICE_PACKET_LIMIT) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (detectedScanners->type1==true || detectedScanners->type2==true) {
        *interface = d->name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In non-blocking mode, `pcap_next_ex()` will return 0 if there are no packets available to read, and will *NOT* return any packet information, so, if it returned 0, you should *not* look at anything that `header` or `packet_data` points to.

I.e., do

```
while ((res = pcap_next_ex(fp, &header, &pkt_data)) >=0) {
    if (res != 0) {
        struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(pkt_data +  sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr*)(pkt_data + (iph->ihl*4)  + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        u_int destPort = ntohs(udph->dest);

        if (destPort==TYPE1_DATA_PORT || destPort==TYPE1_GPS_PORT) {
            detectedScanners->type1 = true;
        } else if (destPort==TYPE2_DATA_PORT || destPort==TYPE2_STATUS_PORT || destPort==TYPE2_NMEA_PORT) {
            detectedScanners->type2 = true;
        }

        if (++packetCounter > FIND_DEVICE_PACKET_LIMIT) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note, however, that your program will continuously spin, consuming CPU, in that loop, *forever*.  This means that you'll never look past the first device.

What you probably really want to do is:

- open *all* the devices, putting their `pcap_t *`s into an array, and put them into non-blocking mode;
- for each of the devices, call `pcap_get_selectable_fd()` on UN*X and `pcap_getevent()` on Windows, and save the result of that call into an array (you can have parallel arrays, or an array of structures with the `pcap_t *` and the `int` or `HANDLE` as members);
- in the loop, use `select()` or `poll()` on all of the `int`s from `pcap_get_selectable_fd()` on UN*X or `WaitForMultipleObjects()` on all of the `HANDLE`s from `pcap_getevent()` on Windows and, when `select()`/`poll()`/`WaitForMultipleObjects()` returns, try reading a packet from *each* of the `pcap_t *`s using `pcap_next_ex()`, and process it if you get a packet.

That way, you scan on all devices in parallel, and don't spin the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the post. This looks promising. I overlooked the fact that I was still using >= to check the result of `pcap_next_ex`. It won't spin forever, because I can increment the packetCounter each round, and after 20 attempts, it's done. This should be fine, as the data is coming in extremely fast, but if not, the other method sounds great (it actually sounds the best if it can work like I think it can). Will give it a try and accept answer if it works out!

Comment: The solution involving opening all devices (outlined by the bullets) was indeed the best solution for this problem for future reference.